# About the formation of protein

Tags: proteins

There is a question in my textbook which asks: "What does the glucose produced from photosynthesis form?" However one of the answers said that glucose forms protein.  But I'm quite sure that amino acids form protein, don't they?  I would be grateful if anyone out there could help me out.

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here? _Hint: glucose is an energy source_.

Comment: I only know that excess protein can be converted into glucose in our body for energy, but i dont know how glucose can be converted into protein :(

Comment: Who asked _converting_ glucose into protein? Also, it is [possible](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/13022652) to convert gluocse to amino acids.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "one of the answer" ? Was this a multiple-choice thing ? What was the exact sentence involved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photosynthesis results into formation of a carbon skeleton (a 3C or 6C skeleton). These newly formed carbon skeleton can be used to form a large number of bio-molecules which are required by a cell. For example the glucose can enter into aerobic respiration and the intermediates thus formed are used for synthesis of several molecules.
[image: Amphibolic nature of TCA]

As you can specifically see from the above figure, alpha ketoglutarate is converted into glutamate which is then used for synthesis of proteins.

Alpha ketoglutarate is a keto acid can easily be aminated to give rise to amino acid.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. The often taught idea that photosynthesis produces glucose is an oversimplification. It would be better to think of it as a process of carbon fixation. The resulting organic molecules can be used to synthesize the precursors of macromolecules (nucleic acids, fatty acids, amino acids and carbohydrates).

Comment: In addition, it is not necessary that glucose will be synthesized and then it will be used for respiration. The triose (3C carbohydrate) can directly enter into glycolytic pathway.